# Survival event simulation with time-varying confounders and treatment-confounder feedback

Tags: survival, simulation, causality

I'm trying to generate survival data that contain time-varying treatment and time-varying confounding. The goal is to test inverse probability of treatment method developed by Hernan and James Robins.

Ideally, the simulation process could be realistic, i.e., reflecting some real physical/physiological processes (e.g., patient progression, nuclear decay, events in computing cluster, etc). The simulator should be able to generate a sequence of time-varying confounders, a sequence of actions, and the final event time. It's even better if we have access to the groundtruth hazard curves.

I haven't been able to find a good reference. Could anyone give a pointer to existing literature or possible directions that I can explore?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Havercroft & Didelez (2012)](http://doi.wiley.com/10.1002/sim.5472) wrote exactly about this problem. You can also check out the `simcausal` [R package](https://cran.r-project.org/package=simcausal), which provides an interface for simulating data for causal inference applications.